# How high can a PC jump normally?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, movement

So I was playing 5e a while back, and we were ambushed by a large group of kobolds. I had to run past them taking damage from attacks of opportunity. If I could get out of their reach with a high jump that would be for the best. I wouldn't have almost cost us the match. How can you tell how high a PC can jump under normal circumstances? I know how *far* they can jump, but it does not explain anything about height.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to know about how high you can go while jumping to move horizontally? I.e. you want to jump over the kobolds, not just jump upwards?

Comment: "If I could get out of their reach with a high jump that would be for the best. I wouldn't have almost cost us the match." If you jumped high enough to leave their reach, you'd provoke attacks from the nearby kobolds. You'd need to make unrealistically high and long jumps and clear multiple kobolds for jumping to be any better than running, unless your plan was to jump up to higher ground.

Comment: Is there something in the rulebook that is unclear or missing? The rules on high jump are quite easy to find, they are the next sub-section after long jump, which you seem to be familiar with.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The rules are on PHB p182:

> When you make a high jump. you leap into the air a number of feet
>   equal to 3 + your Strength modifier if you move at least 10 feet on
>   foot immediately before the jump. When you make a standing high jump,
>   you can jump only half that distance. Either way, each foot you clear
>   on the jump costs a foot of movement. In some circumstances. your
>   DM might allow you to make a Strength (Athletics) check to jump higher
>   than you normally can.

Also you can add a bit of height to your horizontal jump with an Athletics check.

Comment: Maybe improve the answer by mentioning the class-specific bonuses to (high-) jumping distances available to monks (Step of the Wind) and rogues with the Thief archetype (Second-Story Work), and the benefits of the Athlete feat. Maybe also the _jump_ spell.

Comment: @marq sounds like you've got an answer there :)

Comment: @Marq The question asked about normal circumstances, not a theoretical maximum.