# How high can my monk jump?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, monk

My monk has a movement of 50ft and a +4 strength bonus (18 STR).  My computation for my maximum jump is start of 10 ft.

I arrive at a high jump of 14 ft + remaining movement which is rounded down of 25 ft + extra movement of dash (step of the wind)=+50ft
Max jump = 89 ft?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take our [tour] when you have the chance for a free badge. Are you asking if you are understanding the jump rules properly or what the maximum jump height is?

Comment: I edited your question to reflect that you're asking about *your monk* and not a theoretical maximum for any monk. If you don't agree, you can [roll back my edit](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/136246/edit).

Comment: @korvinstarmast 18.. Just asking if my computation is right... And as you see there is my computation of "High jump"

Comment: Related on [How high can a PC jump normally?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101904/how-high-can-a-pc-jump-normally)

Comment: Are you trying to combine a long jump and a high jump?

Comment: James, here is a [Related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/57283/22566)

Answer (score 24):

Under normal circumstances your high jump would reach 7 ft (3 + your Strength mod of +4).

Certain abilities and spells can increase this, so you would need to give more details on your monk.

Refer to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101904/how-high-can-a-pc-jump-normally)

You seem to be under a bit of a misconception on what the jumping rule is actually saying and adding everything up(?). The high jump rule is saying that

1. *If you have a run-up of 10ft* then your height when jumping is 3 + your Strength mod. This is the number of feet you leap into the air.
2. If you do *not* have a run-up and just try and leap straight up
   then you only leap half that amount. i.e. 3 + your Strength mod,
   then divide that by two. In your case that would be 3.5 ft
3. The distance you jump is subtracted from the number of feet you can move in a round in order to calculate how much movement you have left. So if you run 10ft then jump forward 7ft, you would still have 33ft of movement left (50ft movement minus the 10ft minus the 7ft jump).

Comment: @James. I apologize if I misinterpreted your question, but if I failed to answer it, that's all it was - a misinterpretation. It would be more helpful if you actually explained how it failed to answer your question.

Answer (score 17):

## You can High Jump a max 14' with resource expenditure

The [jumping](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/adventuring#Jumping) rules are detailed in the PHB(p. 182):

> When you make a high jump you leap into the air a number of feet equal to 3 + your Strength modifier if you move at least 10 feet on foot immediately before the jump. When you make a standing high jump, you can jump only half that distance. Either way, each foot you clear on the jump costs a foot of movement. (Basic Rules, p. 67)

That gives you a maximum of 7' because you are taking the 10' movement prior to jumping so can add your Strength modifier to the base 3' from jumping.

However, you have the option to spend a Ki Point resource for **[Step of the Wind](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/classes#Monk)**. This allows you to (my emphasis):

> ..spend 1 ki point to take the Disengage or Dash action as a bonus action on your turn, and **your jump distance is doubled for the turn**.

Jump Distance includes both types of Jumping described: High Jump and Long Jump. It is the distance you could do either action.

This doubles your total jump height to 14'.

### Where you went wrong in your calculation

Your mistake was involving your actual movement values(outside of needing 10' to jump your maximum distance) in your calculations for High Jump Distance. The methodology for calculating Jump Distance does not include your movement speed except as a maximum boundary (If you only had a move of 20', you wouldn't be able to jump 14' because you need the initial 10' and only have 10' remaining of total movement.)

Comment: Are Jump Distance and Jump Height the same concept in the rules?

Comment: Then why does your post imply that Step of the Wind affects jump _height_? The wording of the ability appears to be about Distance.

Comment: @MooingDuck Ah, gotcha. The different jumping mechanics are Long Jump and High Jump. Distance would apply to either Jump. Sorry!

Answer (score 5):

### High Jump of 14'; movement is reduced by 10' + jump height/length

Your high jump is pretty straight forward: 7' up with a strength of 18 and the monk using a 10' start.  A 3.5 foot vertical leap from a standing start.  (How far the bottom of your feet are from the ground at the jump's apex).

While "jump distance doubling" seems to fit the long jump and high jump is measured in "height," assume a ruling where height is doubled so you can high jump 14' with a 10' running start, or 7' with a standing start using *step of the wind*.   (I'd rule favorably on doubling the jump height, since cool monk stuff is cool!)
**How high can the monk jump?**  14' up if *Step of the Wind* doubles your high jump.

> [Jumping](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=67)
>   Your Strength determines how far you can jump.
>   High Jump.
>   When you make a high jump you leap into the air a number of feet equal to 3 + your Strength modifier if you move at least 10 feet on foot immediately before the jump.  When you make a standing high jump, you can jump only half that distance.  Either way, each foot you clear on the jump *costs a foot of movement*. (Basic Rules, p. 67)

#### What happens to the movement with Step of the Wind?

Your question appears to mix jumping and movement.

> I arrive at a high jump of 14 ft + remaining movement which is rounded
>   down of 25 ft + extra movement of dash (step of the wind)=+50ft Max
>   jump = 89 ft?

You used 14 feet of movement, +10 for the running start. 100 -24 = 76 feet of movement left if you want to use it all.

For a running long jump, 10 feet of movement, cover up to 18' (your strength score, doubled to 36' using SoTW).  100 - 46 equals *54 feet of movement left when using *step of the wind* and dash* after your maxed out running long jump.

> **Long Jump**
>   When you make a long jump, you cover a number of feet up to your *Strength score* if you move at least 10 feet on foot immediately before the jump.  When you make a standing long jump, you can leap only half that distance. Either way, **each foot you clear on the jump costs a foot of  movement**.  (Basic Rules, p. 67)

Comment: If you're getting into the remainder of movement bit, you may need to include that you can take Disengage rather than Dash for Step of the Wind. That changes your values.

Comment: @NautArch He said "dash" in the question so I stuck to that.

Comment: @korvinstarmast.. So my monk can jump 76 feet vertically?

Comment: @JamesBryanHGamboa no, that's movement available after the 14' vertical jump if you are using step of the wind to dash.

Comment: So you can't dash your jumping and you can't dash your flying you mean dash is sole purpose is extra movement meant for walking.. But if you read jumping it is cost movement? So my monk will just lay down just like sleeping and use "StoW" and can move 75feet... Hahaha stupid monk 5e hahahaha 3.5 is much better jumping though

Comment: So the maker of wizard of coast is wrong and you are right..... Every foot jumped costs movement, so you can jump farther than your current speed if you take the Dash action. — Jeremy Crawford

Comment: @JamesBryanHGamboa If you look at the Jump spell, which triples your jumping distance, and apply it to the running  long jump, that's where the dash provides you enough movement to jump long distances.  You asked about vertical leap, and you were answered.  If you believe that the dash applies vertically, that's up to you.  "Further" and "Higher" are not the same word.  You aren't trading movement for high jumping.  High jumping is clearly identified as a function of strength.  A problem arises if one tries to jump further than one has movement, which is the long jump case.

Comment: @JamesBryanHGamboa For example, if you normally have 30' of movement, and you want to do a running long jump of 48 feet (STR of 16) you need to "dash" do have enough movement to jump that many feet.  You'll have 2 feet left over, since you need a total of 10+48 feet of movement to cover that distance.  Each foot your jump costs a foot of movement.  That's how the mechanic works.  I have bolded that citation from the rules in the answer.

Comment: @JamesBryanHGamboa That quote is around magic increasing your jumping distance and how that relates to the maximum cap for movement (either the cap from the jump or the cap from your total move.) It is still very much in support of these answers.

Comment: @korvinstarmast "You aren't trading movement for high jumping. High jumping is clearly identified as a function of strength" high jump needs movement sir.. And sir i will be convinced that you are right that you can'tuse dash vertically, if you are not agree on using dash action under water to go deeper and the used of dash while flying. Dash action gives extra movement.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about your movement, that does not affect how high you can jump.

The PHB states that jump height = your strength modifier + 3 (if you have a 10ft running start). That’s it.  The only thing your movement has to do with it is that you have to subtract how high you jump from your remaining movement.

Let’s say your str modifier is +3. That means you can jump 6 feet off of the ground.  If you have 30 ft of movement to start with, you would have to subtract that 6 ft jump, leaving you with 24 ft of movement.  Step of the wind doubles your jump distance. In MY mind distance is vertical or horizontal, so that 6 becomes 12.  You would then subtract that 12 from your doubled movement, which would be 60, leaving you with 48 ft of movement left.  That's how your jump and your movement relate to each other.

Forget about movement when high jumping (until after the jump, so you can subtract that distance).

Comment: This doesn't really add anything more than is already covered in other answers and seems to be more of a comment in reply to comments on other answers (which is not what the answer section is for), rather than an independent answer. It *does* provide an answer to the question though, which is good, so I won't flag as "not an answer".